# How to compute the following (joint) mgf's for random variables (vectors) with the following (joint) pmf's

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

I have to compute the following (joint) mgf's for random variables (vectors) with the following (joint) pmf's, but I have no clue how it works. I have no background knowledge in Probability Theory and reading the theory did not bring me far.

1) $f_X (k)$ = $\frac{1}{k(k+1)}$, $k ≥ 1$

$E[e^{tX}]$ = $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}$ $\frac{e^{kt}}{k(k+1)}$ = $-e^{-t}(-e^t+e^tlog(1-e^t)-log(1-e^t))$ by using the Taylor series of $log(1-x)$

2) $f_X (k)$ = ${n+k-1}\choose{k}$$p^n(1-p)^k$, $k ≥ 0$

3) $f_{X,Y} (i, k)$ = $(e−1)e^{−2k+1}k^i/i!$, $i, k ≥ 0$

4) $f_{X,Y} (i, k)$ = $(1−α)(β −α)α^iβ^{k−i−1}$, $0 ≤ k ≤ i$, where $0 < α < $min{1,β}

Any help would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: use the formula $\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}(X=k)e^{kt} =\sum_{k=0}^\infty f_X(k)e^{kt}$. Can you find its analogue for a random vector $(X,Y)$?

Comment: Thanks, I shall try to get an answer

Comment: I do not get an answer for the first one. Is there a way you can help me further?

Comment: Can you share your attempt and where you get stuck?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: The rest is elementary computations using the Taylor series of $\log(1-x)$. See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+x%5Ej%2F%28j%28j%2B1%29%29%2C+j%3D1..infinity

Comment: I again edited my question with my attempt

Answer (score 0):

Hint on 2)

If a coin is thrown repeatedly with probability $p$ to land on heads and $X$ denotes the number of tails that show up before the $n$-th head shows up then $f_X$ will be the PMF of $X$.

Now be aware that we can write:$$X=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n$$where $X_1$ stands for the number of tails that show up before the first head, $X_2$ for the number of tails that show up between the first and the second head, et cetera.

Then the $X_i$ are iid with Geometric distribution: $P(X_i=k)=p(1-p)^k$

Now if $g(t)$ denotes the MGF of $X_1$ then we can find the MGF of $X$ on base of:$$\mathbb Ee^{tX}=\mathbb Ee^{tX_1+\cdots+tX_n}=\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb Ee^{tX_i}=\prod_{i=1}^n g(t)=g(t)^n$$

Comment: I know how to solve it for $f_X (k)$ = ${n}\choose{k}$$p^n(1-p)^k$, $k ≥ 0$, but I am stuck at the part where the binomial coefficient is ${n+k-1}\choose{k}$